# Invoking an MMC Snap-in function from Windows command shell: is it possible?

Tags: windows, terminal, automation, scheduled-tasks, mmc

I need to execute a MMC Snap-in function from the Command Shell of a Windows computer. I need it to schedule this command in the same Windows PC and executes in background.

Probably this questions could seem a little bit strange but I have a program that creates a debug log only through its MMC Snap-in console. And I need to automatise this task to programatically read this log!

Dows anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [MMC 2.0 Automation Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815049(v=vs.85).aspx) via COM from Powershell. Possibly nasty, but workable.

To get started with Powershell:

```
$mmc = New-Object -ComObject MMC20.Application
$mmc.Load("path\to\some.msc")
```

1. You'll probably have to be admin.
2. The API is pretty awful but you should be able to access the data through it.
   [Here's a VB example of extracting stuff from the a snap-in's items.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa815171(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AutoIT:](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for
>   automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a
>   combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control
>   manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or
>   reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is
>   also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of
>   Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!

[image]